# Is there a format for years datas?

Tags: r

I have years in my data set from 1988 to 2019.

I did this to use it as factor (for charts, etc..) :

```
DTA$ANNEE <- as.factor(DTA$ANNEE)
```

But, I would like to use other function on this data set, like :

```
max(DTA$ANNEE)
max(DTA$ANNEE-1) # By the way, is it the right syntax for : 2019-1 = 2018 ?
max(DTA$ANNEE-2)
max(DTA$ANNEE-3)
max(DTA$ANNEE-4)
max(DTA$ANNEE-5)
```

I tried with `DTA$ANNEE <- as.numeric(DTA$ANNEE)` but 2019 became "1", 2018 became "2", 2017 became "3", etc.. I don't understand.

The purpose of this is to get the five last years of my data set and rename columns with it on other tables.

Is there a specific format for years?

For example, will this function work?

```
droplevels(DTA[DTA$ANNEE %in% max(DTA$ANNEE-2), ])
```

Thank you

Comment: That's because it's a factor. Try `DTA$ANNEE <- as.numeric(as.character(DTA$ANNEE))`

Comment: it's probably better to use `as.factor()` when you need the year as a factor than the other way around. Most charts don't even need it as a factor since it's ordinal anyway.

Comment: Oh, thank you, it seems to be ok :) Also, the right way for  my next purpose is max((DTA$ANNEE)-1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
as.numeric(as.character(DTA$ANNEE))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, it might be useful to simply have a column both for your factor and numeric data.

```
DTA$ANNEE_factor <- as.factor(DTA$ANNEE)
```

Depending on whether you want a numeric or factor year, use the correct column.

Note: A numeric year should simply be 2019. if the value is '2019' (with quotes), it will be considered a character value.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your feedback, it works well :)

Before publication of my results, I need to rename columns like this :

```
colnames(base_graphs)[3] <- "ANNEE_" + max(DTA$ANNEE)
```

It doesn't works.. Is there a way to add "text" + function in a colname ?